# Database file paths for Named Instances in AAG's

Tags: sql-server-2014, availability-groups, high-availability

I have configured a 2 node AAG setup with named instances say N1 and N2. During the AAG creation and database seeding from N1 , I got an error saying that N2 did not have any folders/path similar to N1 and I could not continue. So I created another Directory path for the database files with the same name as that on Node 1. Will this work? Am I missing anything else? Please clarify

Answer (score 2):

> I have configured a 2 node AAG setup with named instances say N1 and N2.

I wouldn't use named instances, default instances will cause less issues in the long run. We'll get to one of those issues...

> During the AAG creation and database seeding from N1 , I got an error saying that N2 did not have any folders/path similar to N1 and I could not continue.

Correct. Since you're using named instances, the installation directory names will be different which is why you're receiving the error. In order for the databases to seed they must have identical folder structures.

> So I created another Directory path for the database files with the same name as that on Node 1. Will this work?

If the folders are identical, then yes. You'll also need to put the proper security on the new folders.

Comment: Okay. Can you please explain about the issues. Thanks

Comment: @user2923332 Not in this forum, you'll really want to read up on how availability groups work and see where your common pitfalls are. You can do some generic web searches about availability groups as well. No point in reiterating entire websites. The AG Wizard will search for common items before creation as well.

Comment: Sean, we already have them in our prod - but wanted to go with Named instances to make our monitoring efforts more easier. Thanks for the help!